# Whatsapp Cloud Message not getting delivered

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

1. My Template is approved by Meta
2. My Token is working fine
3. Language code is correctly updated (en_US)
4. Permission is all set properly in the Meta App

Below is my Node Js code,

```
app.post("/send-confirmation", async (req, res) => {
  const { phoneNo, bookingId, name, tripType, origin, destination, bookedDate, bookedTime, carType, distance, estimate } = req.body;

  const postData = JSON.stringify({
      messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
      recipient_type: 'individual',
      to: [`91${phoneNo}`], // Phone number of the customer
      type: 'template',
      template: {
          name: 'booking_confirmation',
          language: {
              code: 'en_US',
          },
          components: [
              {
                  type: 'header',
                  parameters: [
                      {
                          type: 'image',
                          image: {
                              link: 'https://www.examle.com/logo-1.png',
                          },
                      },
                  ],
              },
              {
                  type: 'body',
                  parameters: [
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${bookingId}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${name}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${phoneNo}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${tripType}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${origin}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${destination}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${bookedDate} ${bookedTime}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${carType}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${distance}`,
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'text',
                          text: `${estimate}`,
                      },
                  ],
              }
          ],
      },
  });
  try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url:
          "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/117505268034839/messages",
        data: postData,
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      });
      console.log(response.data); // or do something with the response data
      res.send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.send(error);
    }
});
```

I get this as a response from Meta after the request is made,

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "input": "[\"917299568568\"]",
            "wa_id": "917299568568"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE3Mjk5NTY4NTY4FQIAERgSM0MzMkE1NUVENTA2QTNCRUNBAA=="
        }
    ]
}
```

But, I'm not sure why the message is not getting delivered. Please help what I'm missing here

Answer (score 0):

This is very funny, but when you are using the api in development mode, first you have to send a message to the test number, otherwise you will not be able to receive messages

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531542/how-to-send-a-text-message-with-whatsapp-cloud-api/72554131#72554131) for a better explanation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35132238)